# psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "default-workgroupxxx.redshift-serverlessx" (172.31.1.60), port 5439 failed: Connection timed out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

I am trying to Load data to AWS Redshift Serverless using a python psycopy2

```
#from warehouseInterface import Warehouse

import boto3
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import psycopg2
#any file in python is module

class AWSWarehouse():
    def connect(self, config):
        #redshift_client = boto3.client('redshift', aws_access_key_id=config['AKIA6OOMDUKKNSXXXX'],
                            # aws_secret_access_key=config['OEur3QbGL2vhRQyG4Rlicu/pvhFBIYAzFjjJnKj/'],
                            # region_name=config['ap-south-1'])

        # redshift Connection details
        redshift_endpoint = 'default-workgroup.xxxx.ap-south-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com'
        redshift_port = '5439'
        redshift_database = 'dev'
        redshift_user = 'admin'
        redshift_password = 'password'
        
        print("hello")

        # setting up connection with redshift
        redshift_conn = psycopg2.connect(   
                                         
            host=redshift_endpoint,
            port=redshift_port,
            database=redshift_database,
            user=redshift_user,
            password=redshift_password
        )
        
        print("Nasa")
        
        return redshift_conn
    
    
    def execute_query(self, query, conn):
        return super().execute_query(query)
```

In this above code i have hardcoded the thing and added two debugging lines print hello which is working fine but it is not printing Nasa Which clears the thing that it problem in aws redshift side

I even have notice one more thing that when I am trying to change password in Redshift, I get the message that password is changed successfully but upon rechecking I can see that password is not changed

This is main.py

```
#take data from tranform and load itin redshift

from DataTransform import Asteriod_Tranform
from DataLoading.MyWareHouse import AWSRedshift

res = Asteriod_Tranform.mydic
#print(res)

name = res['name']
closeData = res['close_approach_data']
closeDate = res['close_approach_date']
#count = res['count']


# Creating an instance of the AWSWarehouse class
aws_warehouse = AWSRedshift.AWSWarehouse()
print(aws_warehouse)

# Assuming you have the necessary AWS configuration in a dictionary
config = {
    'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': 'your_access_key',
    'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY': 'your_secret_key',
    'AWS_REGION': 'your_region',
    # other configuration parameters...
}



# Call the connect method
connection = aws_warehouse.connect(config)

print(connection)

create_table_query = """
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    name VARCHAR(255),
    closeData VARCHAR(255),
    closeDate DATE,
    
);
"""

# Call the execute_query method to create the table
aws_warehouse.execute_query(create_table_query, connection)

# Close the connection after creating the table
connection.close()
```

Error which I am getting is

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    connection = aws_warehouse.connect(config)
  File "/home/mayank/Desktop/Project/DE/NASA/DataLoading/MyWareHouse/AWSRedshift.py", line 25, in connect
    redshift_conn = psycopg2.connect(   
  File "/home/mayank/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "default-workgroup.993102373524.ap-south-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com" (172.31.1.60), port 5439 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the Redshift Database is not accepting connections on port 5439. You would need to allow connection on port 5439 in the Redshift security group to allow connections from the network you are trying to access Redshift.

Refer to the documentation below - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-refusal-failure-issues.html